# Debugging standalone Spring Boot application (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: spring, debugging, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am using Intellij IDEA 14.1 and I am trying to debug the most basic standalone Spring Boot 1.2.5 application. Would someone please tell me how to do that?

I've read http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html but have not been successful in making it work. The easiest would be to disable the forking that Spring Boot is using when debugging, but again, I was not successful in doing so. (-Dfork=false?)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why even use maven to run? Just run the class containing the main from IntelliJ and run it in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue above did not require **anything specific related to Spring Boot**. I have found that there was an issue in the error log of the IDE `saying can't proxy final class class com.sun.tools.jdi.ClassTypeImpl` which was related to an outdated JRebel plugin I had installed in my IDE. The issue was then resolved by updating the outdated JRebel plugin. Afterwards, it is the usual process as if you were debugging any other application

Answer (score 6):

I am confused.

You have a `main` method that starts your standalone Spring Boot application, right? Well, right click on that and choose `Debug 'YourApp'`

Comment: That would be the logical thing to do. However, in this case, I am just getting `Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52685', transport: 'socket'`

Comment: Well, you have some customizations to your  run config. Edit your run configuration and check the VM options. Better yet, create a blank new run configuration and you should be fine. I am doing this all the time.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new remote configuration in IntelliJ it gives you the command line arguments for remote debugging.

- open edit configurations
- add new remote configuration
- Now the configuration tab on the right lists the Java command line arguments for running the jar in debug mode.

For example, start your Spring Boot application with:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8008 -jar yourapplication.jar
```

Then select the debug icon to enable your breakpoints.